# count number of same value column in data base using phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, count

i have the following table in phpmysql data base with three column , **country , name and id(primary)** show in html table one.
it has multiple entry , i want to count the value and display it ( html table two.)
what will be the mysql queries used for creating the second table

**html table One**

```
| id    | Country     | name |
|------:|------------:|-----:|
| 1     |USA          |   John
| 2     |USA          |   kAVI
| 3     | USA         |   Manoj
| 4     | USA         |   vijay
| 5     |Japan        |   Will
| 6     |Japan        |   Robert
| 7     |india        |   Vikas
| 8     |india        |   Monika
| 9     |india        |   Jecisa
```

**html table two**

```
|id   |Country|Count|
|----:|----..:|----:|
|1    |USA    |    4|
|2    |Japan  |    2|
|3    |india  |    3|
```

[image: actual tablese]

Comment: usa is only 4 times in the table

Comment: yes i corrected it .

Comment: `Select min(id) as id, count(*) as cnt, country from tableOne group by country`

Comment: The min(id) won't give you the right answer. You need to use row_number after group by. Here it is: with 
t as 
(select  country
        ,count(*) as count
        ,min(id) as id
from     html_table_One 
group by country
order by id) 

select row_number() over (order by id) as id
      ,country
      ,count
from   t

Comment: Reopened. The `id` column adds here an element that does not appear in the post it was allegedly a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using group by to achieve the count and row_number to generate the id.

```
with 
t as 
(select  country
        ,count(*) as count
        ,min(id) as id
from     html_table_One 
group by country
order by id) 

select row_number() over (order by id) as id
      ,country
      ,count
from   t
```

| id | country | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 4 |
| 2 | Japan | 2 |
| 3 | india | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba80218c854ef226d6007e7de79bf6fc&hide=1)